# alternative for the var self = this pattern 

Tags: javascript

I am looking for var self = this alternative plan.

```
var Animal = function(name){
  this.name = name;
  this.arr = [1,2,3,4];
  this.inc = function(num){
      return num + 1;
  };

  this.fireArr = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.arr.forEach(function(item){
      console.log(self.inc(item));
    });

  };

};

var dog = new Animal("dog");
console.log(dog.fireArr());
```

My fiddle is here.

http://jsfiddle.net/haradashinya/TtYpc/

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to make sure the function is called with the right `this` value:

```
function fireArr() {
    this.arr.forEach(function(item){
        console.log(this.inc(item));
    }.bind(this));
}
```

But imho the `self` (`that`, `_this`) variable is easier to understand, because it directly states that not the normal `this` value is used, although one would expect it (e.g. in an event handler, or jQuery's `each()`). Especially on long functions, where you don't see the `bind()` in the end, this is of importance. Also, some ancient browsers do not support `bind()` and you would need to shim it.

So, for any in-place *function expressions* I recommend the use of a dereferencing variable.

But it can be of great use when you have a method defined somewhere, normally using `this` to point to the current object as it is common in that context, and then the method should be used somewhere else. Instead of a `var self`-wrapper, you can and should use `bind` for simplicity and clarity. Your example offers quite a good demo (assuming the `inc` method used the `this` keyword):

```
this.arr.forEach( this.inc.bind(this) );
```

(although [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) allows us to pass a custom `this` argument - event attachers for example don't)

Comment: Make sure you shim `.bind` as it is not supported in older browsers.

Comment: @Anthony: In a browser that supports `.forEach`, I'm sure `.bind` is supported as well.

Comment: @FelixKling Safari and Opera don't agree `:)` Those two got `.bind()` only recently in their latest versions.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation. bind(this) plan is reasonable for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the second argument to `forEach`, which is the `this` value.

```
this.arr.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(this.inc(item));
}, this);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the `inc` function doesn't use the `this` value, so it doesn't need to be a method. You can define it as a local function:

```
var Animal = function ( name ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];

    var inc = function ( num ) {
        return num + 1;
    };

    this.fireArr = function () {
        this.arr.forEach(function ( item ) {
            console.log( inc( item ) );
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: I think in this case the function should be public - but its true, it is very static.

Comment: Oh, It is very beautiful pattern at my example. Thanks.

Comment: @Bergi Yea, that would make more sense (in this case, at least). Having it as a local function of the constructor makes only sense if it uses the arguments or local variables of the constructor. Otherwise, it makes more sense to define it on one of the outer scopes.