# JavaScript array foreach function needs more explanation

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I confused with `Array.prototype.forEach()` function arguments, especially "**thisp**" (the second argument).

Below is the original function and I added *document.write()* inside to check:

```
Array.prototype.forEach=function(res , thisp)
{
  var len = this.length;
  if (typeof res != "function")
    throw new TypeError();

  //var thisp = arguments[1];
  document.write("cekkk<br/>");
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    if (i in this)
        document.write(thisp+", "+this[i]+", "+i+"<br/>");
      res.call(thisp, this[i], i, this);
  }
};
```

The result is:

```
cekkk
undefined, 4, 0
undefined, 1, 1
undefined, 3, 2
undefined, 5, 3
undefined, 6, 4
```

If I **remove the `thisp` argument**, like below:

```
Array.prototype.forEach=function(res)
{
  var len = this.length;
  if (typeof res != "function")
    throw new TypeError();

  //var thisp = arguments[1];
  document.write("cekkk<br/>");
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    if (i in this)
        document.write(this[i]+", "+i+"<br/>");
      res.call(this[i], i, this);
  }
};
```

The result is:

```
cekkk
4, 0
1, 1
3, 2
5, 3
6, 4
```

My array is `[4,1,3,5,6]`.

Can somebody explain what are the function's arguments used for? What is the data type of `thisp` argument and why `thisp` is `undefined`?

Comment: Why are you *defining* the ordinarily built-in `.forEach()` function?

Comment: You *may* want to look at [my question on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44529/foreach-and-nodelist) and the posted answers for an illustration on `forEach`.

Comment: i just wondering, maybe it can help me understanding the javascript function more.

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks, but still not get whats the browser do (code step) when i call forEach.

Comment: the argument sets what "this" means inside your callback. It's not as useful for forEach() as for filter() and map(), but it has several key uses in making generic functions. it's always an object, but it can act like a string or number when needed. it can allow map() to act much like reduce() if you use this as a collector. If you are seeing it as undefined, you need to set it when you call [].forEach: [1,2,3].forEach(fnCallback, myThis). consider a function like function say(a){ alert(a[this])};  if my array was full of <a> tags, i can alert each href like so: arr.forEach(say, "href")

Comment: ive made these 2 function:
function fnCallback(element, index, array) {
    console.log("X[" + index + "] = " + element);
}
function myThis(val){
 console.log(val[this]);
}
fnCallback gives some result, but myThis return nothing

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/11818590/1048572, http://stackoverflow.com/q/19445599/1048572, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13007527/1048572 for where you need this. Also read [the docs for `.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: If you're going to mess with a `.forEach()` replacement, you should look at the code [posted at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill)

Comment: thanks to Bergi and Pointy. i got something, thisp is an optional parameter right? such as a variable to be processed on forEach function. and the other is just a callback function. thanks for the answers but correct me again if i'm still wrong

Comment: Yes. That's [how it is documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), that's how you apparently used it, and that's how it should have been explained at the place where you found this code.